# How to get the user info on who deleted an account?

Tags: 7

In Drupal 7, a user was removed. As an administrator I reviewed the permission and role report from administration menu. But couldn't find the information. Is there any other way I can find the info on who has deleted the user? Is this information stored in database table? If so how can I get it?

Thanks
Venkat.

Comment: You need one of a handful of auditing/logging modules that tracks actions like these for deeper details. https://www.drupal.org/project/audit_log

Comment: This module is not supported for drupal 7 and also I can't install it on production. Any possibility to use database query? If so which table(s) has the information

Comment: They don't capture this level of detail. That's why you need a contributed module.

Comment: And there is a release for it https://www.drupal.org/project/audit_log/releases/7.x-1.3

Comment: Thanks for your help.